# select max value of a column in table with no rows

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle10g

I am using oracle database

While inserting a row in a table, i need to find the max value of a column and increment it by 1, and use that value in row i am inserting.

```
INSERT INTO dts_route 
   (ROUTE_ID, ROUTE_UID, ROUTE_FOLDER)
VALUES (
                        (SELECT MAX(ROUTE_ID) + 1 FROM  route) ,
                        ROUTE_UID,
                        ROUTE_FOLDER)
```

This works fine if their is at least one entry in table.
But returns null when their are no entries in table.

How can i get default value of 1 when their are no entries in table.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ROUTE_ID),0) ...
```

Comment: @changed You must be warned using this approach you're in risk to get duplicated values in systems with concurrency.  The risk is proportional to the number of concurrent transactions.  I warn you as it looks is just what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 11):

This is not a safe way of creating an auto-increment field. You can use an Oracle sequence to achieve this goal.

As for the null, you can use `NVL` to give a default value (say, 0) in case the function returns null.

Comment: +1 and I wish I could vote multiple times.  MAX(key) + 1 is a buggy, inefficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use sequence for the ID. You need to create sequence. See below link

http://www.basis.com/onlinedocs/documentation/b3odbc/sql_sequences.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO dts_route 
   (ROUTE_ID)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(r.route_id), 0) +1
  FROM ROUTE r
```

...but you really should be using a [sequence](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) to populate the value with a sequential numeric value:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dts_route_seq;
```

...

```
INSERT INTO dts_route 
   (ROUTE_ID)
SELECT dts_route_seq.NEXTVAL
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Make sure you use NOCACHE on the sequence if you absolutely need it to increment by 1, otherwise you could see the numbers jump by a factor of your cache amount (aging out of cache issue).

Comment: @tbone: Last person I chatted with tested, and didn't see issues across sessions.

Comment: Just sending a warning to someone who may want to use CACHE option and expecting +1 each/every time.  Our DBAs did turned on caching once, expecting a performance gain, and instead we got a not so nice surprise when the sequence numbers were "skipping" values.

Comment: Cached sequences don't have a problem across sessions.  They will skip values if the sequence is used infrequently enough that the cache ages out of the shared pool or if the database is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Set a default for NULL

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(ROUTE_ID),0)
```

though using a sequence might be easier if you don't mind the odd gaps in your route ids

Answer (score 1):

select 0 when null, then it will be 0+1 which is a correct number compared to null+1

`SELECT isnull(MAX(ROUTE_ID),0) + 1 FROM  route`

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about there being gaps in your route ids then create the sequence with the NOCACHE clause:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dts_route_seq NOCACHE;
```

Note that there is a performance hit because Oracle now has to "commit" each time you increment the sequence.